# How to read aloud this math symbol u_a(x)?

Tags: reading-aloud

I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3362912/660389) about u<sub>a</sub>(x) just now.

Then I realized I have no idea how to read aloud the symbol.

Usually I read aloud X<sub>1</sub> as "X one". Should I read aloud u<sub>a</sub>(x) as "u a of x"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would pronounce this:

> f(x)

as *f* of *x*.

And I would pronounce this:

> u<sub>a</sub>

as *u* sub *a*.

Therefore, I would pronounce your expression as: ***u* sub *a* of *x***.

Note: This assumes that  u<sub>a</sub> is a function. If u<sub>a</sub> was a variable and not a function, then I suppose this could be a multiplication expression instead. In that case, I would say: ***u* sub *a* times *x***

Comment: Following the link, we find that in the intended context *u_a* is indeed a function.

Comment: @AntonS - True, but for the sake of completeness, I figured it would be better to leave an answer for the general case.

Comment: If only it were easy to upload an audio file...because  a non-native pronunciation of "a" and "u" could be very different from the one native speakers understand.

Answer (score 0):

**"u<sub>a</sub>(x)".**

Here **u** refers to an object with a dependance to another object **a**.

When **a** is an integer, we commonly say that **u** is a sequence.

More generally, if **a** is a complex number, we can say that **u** is a function of **a** (just like in the idea that **u** is function of **a**, I.E. it depends on **a** ).

So simply, just as you read **"f(x)"**, **f of x**, i'd say **"u<sub>a</sub>(x)"** **u of a**, because you could also write

**u<sub>a</sub>(x) = u(a)(x)**

Comment: Do you mean "dependence on" instead of "dependance to"?